# How to jump to clojure.lang java source?

Tags: java, emacs, clojure, emacs24, cider

When using Cider, doing "M-." above symbol "clojure.lang.ISeq" gives error *"No source available for clojure.lang.ISeq"*.

I see that the source for this file is in "clojure-1.5.1-sources.jar".

How can I make Cider see this source?

Comment: Use https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues

Comment: Are you having the same issue as described [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/715)?

Answer (score 2):

ISeq is a java interface that every seq-able collection in clojure implements. Thus you can't get the source by issuing a (source var). To get to the source you have to peruse the Clojure repo on GitHub. The idea is that the underlying java code that powers Clojure is an implementation detail, therefore it's not designed to be exposed to the users of the language. It's perfectly fine to look at it, but you have to do some digging. You can verify this by eval-ing (javadoc clojure.lang.ISeq).